# Shift key not working on Windows 7 64-bit HP Compaq Pro 6300 SFF

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

Overnight, on a Windows 7 64-bit HP Compaq Pro 6300 SFF desktop PC, in Word and Excel,

- if I press Shift + ‘ - nothing happens.
- if I do it twice I get 2 quotation marks like this “”

If I'm not looking and just type away I get öther” (and no space even thought I type it) instead of “other” – this is only with some “words”” (see – had to double hit the quotes as first one didn’t show and instead I get 2).

Sticky Keys is not on.

Turning Sticky Keys on and off does not resolve this.

Keyboard layout is English (Australian) / US.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a **keyboard icon** in the **system tray**.

Clicking this showed there were two options to choose from:

- US
- US (international)

It was set to US (international).

**Changing it to US** resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Several keyboard settings support easy accesws to special keys and accents on letters such as ó à etc.

This is by typing a marker-key, and the the letter. This is especially usefull when typing non-english languages which make a lot more use of accents on letters.

Example: ' followed by a results in á

To solve this you have 2 options:
- switch to a keyboard setting that does not support this option (such as US) 
- after pressing a marker key press space. (' [space] a will result in 'a)