# windows keyboard language changed unexpectedly

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

The [shift key was not working](https://superuser.com/questions/698994/shift-key-not-working-on-windows-7-64-bit-hp-compaq-pro-6300-sff) on a 64-bit Windows 7 PC.

We resolved this by clicking the keyboard icon in the system tray, and changing from US (international) to US.

4 hours later, the keyboard language has returned back to US (international).

Why did this happen, and how can we prevent it from happening again?  Thanks.

Comment: Keyboard layouts can be changed per application or system-wide. Do you see the language switch when you select another currently opened application? Did you accidentally hit [Alt]+[Shift]? It's a keyboard shortcut to change to the next kayboard language. Using the same keyboard shortcut again reverts the keyboard language to the previous one.

Comment: Since Windows 8 [Crtl]+[Shift] is an additional keyboard shortcut to change the keyboard language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. why did this happened ?
   many reasons , which some got to do with a program you started and that program changed your keyboard layout back to the default.
2. how to prevent this from happening again?
   change your default keyboard layout **or** remove the language you don't use entirely

[image: Region and language]

Comment: Thanks Elazaron.  We deleted the problem language.  You might want to change your answer for future visitors to show how to remove a language that isn't needed.  This will get you more up votes.